# Ranking Google Sheet Info Uniquely

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to rank the data in one column in my google sheet so that there are no duplicate rankings. I've seen some solutions such as `=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$10)+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1`, but the problem is that it increments the duplicates based on occurrence in the sheet.

Let's say my data that I'd like ranked is as follows:

1
1
1
2

The rank order would be 2, 3, 4, 1. The problem is, if I change the second entry to 2 (so that my data is now 1, 2, 1, 2) the ranking order becomes 3, 1, 4, 2 instead of 3, 2, 4, 1 like I want. In the original data, the fourth entry was initially the highest and I'd like it to still have the higher rank, but since the formula counts occurrences it gets demoted. Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with native spreadsheet functions. Spreadsheet formulae have no "awareness" of which values were entered most recently.

You would need to resort to Google Apps Script run on an "on edit" trigger.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.